# Location of pressure tank

Tags: well

[image: drawing of situation]

A well drilling company drilled a well for me and ran lines from the well to my RV pad (AS as in Airstream in the attached image) and in the opposite direction to a shed which will house the pressure tank. I went to hook it all up, but most of the internet and the instructions indicate I would do this with the pressure tank between the well and RV pad.

Can I just cap the other side of the T on the pressure tank, or does it need to be between the well and RV pad?

Answer (score 2):

I would cap off one side of the TEE fitting at the well pump and extend a parallel line from the well location back to the outflow side of the tank. This would be better overall as the water in the tank would get circulated and and the water supply destination would be somewhat more isolated from the pump depending on the exact design of the tank system.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't really matter if your expansion tank is actually in line with your RV, or, as in your case, off of a 'T'. As long as your tank is upstream of your check valve coming off your well, you should be able to take advantage of the the expansion tank to dampen sudden pump induced pressure changes, as well as mitigate water-hammer caused by your fixtures.

The only major difference will be how much turbulence your tank sees, in your case, there will be less, which means the water in it will tend to stagnate and have a greater possibility for things to grow inside it.

Comment: I would not be worried about stagnation of the water. Faucets ariate the water at the tap, city's have huge water tanks and old diphram pressure tanks were never flushed and most had 1-2 inches of mud or silt in the bottom, most pressure tanks today are bladder based and fill and drain from the bottom so there will be water movement. But I would have a pressure regulator at the airstream location. I am guessing the home or future use is close to the pressure tank as this would cost more unless large elevation changes in my opinion.

Comment: @EdBeal water from personal wells isn't chlorinated like city water, thus the types of stuff that can grow inside the thank without some turbidity to wash it off is much higher.

Comment: I have installed quite a few well pumps and pressure tanks , as I said all diphram type pressure tanks always have silt/ mud in the tank this has not caused problems and until about 30 or so years ago was the most common type of pressure tank.

Comment: @EdBeal Then I differ to your experience in the field over my experience in a lab since no one is going to be injecting this water.